# The inverse of the sum of two matrices in *Applied statistical decision theory *.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, self-learning, inverse

I am following *Applied statistical decision theory* [by] Raiffa, Howard. Which can be consulted online [here](http://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=mdp.39015022416351;view=1up;seq=275).

A theorem at the page linked states that if two matrices $A,B$ are non-singular and of dimension $r \times r$, then:

$$(A+B)^{-1} = B^{-1}(B^{-1}+A^{-1})A^{-1} = A^{-1}(A^{-1}+B^{-1})B^{-1} $$

Why is this true?

(a link to a proof will suffice).

Comment: I would choose a different reference to learn decision theory. Just my idea.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören I would be happy to hear your advice.

Comment: http://www.cs.bme.hu/~gyorfi/testinghi.pdf  for example but this is not complete at all. Only the things inside are relavent and modern. A complete book is by E. L. Lehman Testing Statistical Hypothesis. This book is however very heavy. Another book is a bit more engineering oriented but useful. Fundamentals of Statistical Signal Processing, Volume II: Detection Theory. This is easy to understand.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1505628/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(A+B)^{-1}=[B(B^{-1}A+I)]^{-1}=[B(B^{-1}+A^{-1})A]^{-1}$$

Now use that $(XY)^{-1}=X^{-1}Y^{-1}$ to get

$$[B(B^{-1}+A^{-1})A]^{-1}=A^{-1}(B^{-1}+A^{-1})^{-1}B^{-1}$$

Notice that there is a missing $-1$ in your formula.

To get the other equation start with

$$(A+B)^{-1}=[A(I+A^{-1}B)]^{-1}=[A(B^{-1}+A^{-1})B]^{-1}$$
and then

$$[A(B^{-1}+A^{-1})B]^{-1}=B^{-1}(B^{-1}+A^{-1})^{-1}A^{-1}$$